# Jquery: Submit a form without refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services

Im trying to submit a form like this way:

```
<form id="myForm" action="http://example.com/somefile" method="POST">
...
...
...
<input type="submit" id="sendForm" value="send">
</form>
```

the action link its a webservice developed by another developer, so, when i submit the form, the webservice replies me with an URL (http://www.example.com/thanks), what i wanna do is to avoid this webservice reply, and in place, change the url of the redirect, is this possible?

Ive tried too do it with:

```
<script>
    $("#sendForm").click(function () {
       if (form_check_validation()) {
           $("#myForm").submit();
           window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");             
       } else {
           return false;
    //                        event.preventDefault();
       }

    });
</script>
```

But its not working.

Thanks

NOTE: The webservice is in another server, so im having issues with cross-domain origin.

Comment: You can't do this by normal form submit. Unless you use Ajax etc

Comment: Both the form and the setting of `window.location` require navigation and a page can only navigate once, to one or the other. Sending the form data via Ajax may be a possibility provided the page and service satisfy [same-origin rules or both agree upon permitting cross-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). Otherwise, you may need a server-side layer to mediate – submit the form data to it so it can pass that along to the service as well as control the resulting redirect for the client.

Answer (score 0):

https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/ Google is your friend, bud...........

Comment: But if the default submit is prevented how will the data be submitted instead?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this service allows cross origin and you don't want / need to move to a different page, why not use ajax?
You can simply create and ajax call using `$.ajax`.

see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Example:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "POST_URL",
    type: "POST",
    data : formData,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        // Handle server response
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        // Handle error
    }
});
```

Comment: What about cross-domain issues? OP wants to call a web service on another server.

Comment: I assumed he and this developer are working together and that he has cross origin allowed (AJAX is actually a tag in his post) .. but I'll update the answer...

Comment: yep, i want to call to another server! is not in mine! cross-domain issues appear :/

Comment: @rodrigo And you can't have him add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header?

Comment: @Z-Bone no :( its because the developer cannot modify his code! thats so bad!!

Comment: @Rodrigo Well you can always use a simple script on your own server that will create the request to the service and this way will bypass CORS. This script will act as a proxy. Your request is sent from the client to your server and is forwarded to the service and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Ajax. I also recommend that you bind a `submit` event listener to the form so that the submission works correctly also when pressing Enter.

```
$("#myForm").submit(function (event) {
    if (form_check_validation()) {
        form_submit(this);
    } else {
        // ...
    }
    event.preventDefault();
});

function form_submit (form) {
    $.ajax({
        url: form.action,
        type: form.method,
        data: $(form).serialize()
    });
}
```